# IText 7 missing method 'addCustomMetadataExtensions' in .Net?

Tags: .net, itext7, pdfa

I'm currently trying to add extension metadata to a PDFA /A3 using IText7 in .Net (To be ZUGferd compliant).
I found the method in java 'addCustomMetadataExtensions' but it is nowhere to find in .Net?

Am I correct that this method does not exist in .Net?

Comment: seems to be there, looking at the [API documentation](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.13/classi_text_1_1_pdfa_1_1_pdf_a_document.html#a85d6107f6ac5759b259e063c301b9c5a)

Comment: In the .Net world it's `AddCustomMetadataExtensions` instead of `addCustomMetadataExtensions` (capitalization!) but that should be all the difference.

Comment: Oh, I was only looking in the PdfDocument class instead of PdfADocument. Thanks for helping me out!